# LLVM ARM64 assembly: Getting a symbol/label address?

Tags: ios, llvm, arm64

I am porting some 32-bit ARM code to 64-bit and am having trouble determining the 64-bit version of this instruction:

```
ldr  r1, =_fns
```

Where _fns is a symbol defined in some C source file elsewhere in the project.

I've tried the below but both give errors:

```
adr  x1, _fns     <== "error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!"
adrl  x1, _fns    <== "error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic"
```

The assembler is LLVM in the iOS SDK (XCode 7.1).

I've noticed that if _fns is locally defined (i.e. in the same .S file) then "adr x1,_fns" works fine. However that's not a fix as _fns has to be in C code (i.e. in a different translation unit).

What is the right way to do this with LLVM ARM assembler?

Comment: By way of comparison, for most [other](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801d/dom1395139540926.html) [assemblers](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64-Opcodes.html#AArch64-Opcodes) the equivalent A64 'load immediate value' pseudo-op is, er, `ldr x1, =_fns`. I have heard that the LLVM integrated assembler is very limited, and judging from `adrl` I guess it still doesn't support pseudo-ops. Do Apple still include binutils with XCode so you can use an external assembler? (Not touched a Mac myself in several years...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I feed

```
extern char ar[];

char *f()
{
  return ar;
}
```

into the [ELLCC (clang based) demo](http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=340), I get:

Output from the compiler targeting ARM AArch64

```
    .text
    .file   "/tmp/webcompile/_3793_0.c"
    .globl  f
    .align  2
    .type   f,@function
f:                                      // @f
// BB#0:                                // %entry
    adrp    x0, ar
    add x0, x0, :lo12:ar
    ret
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   f, .Lfunc_end0-f


    .ident  "ecc 0.1.13 based on clang version 3.7.0 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.7.0svn)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

The **adrp** instruction gets the "page" address of **ar** into **x0**. The symbol argument to **adrp** translates into a 21 bit PC relative offset to the 4K page in which the symbol resides. That offset is added to the PC to get the actual start of the page. The **add** instruction adds the low 12 bits of the symbol address to get the actual symbol address.

This instruction sequence allows the address of a symbol within +/-4GB of the PC to be loaded.

As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way of getting functionality similar to 32 bit ARM's "=ar" in C. I assembly language, it looks like this will work:

```
        .text
        .file   "atest.s"
        .globl  f
        .align  2
f:
        ldr     x0, p
        ret
        .align  3
p:
        .xword  _fns
```

This is very similar to what the 32 bit ARM does under the hood.

The only reason I started out with the C version was to show how I usually attack a problem like this, especially if I'm not that familiar with the target assembly language.

Comment: Indeed, the `adrl` pseudo-op is specifically a short-cut for an `adrp`/`add` pair, but not everything supports it.

Comment: @Notlikethat: Thanks for pointing that out. In addition, clang's assembler also supports "ldr x0, =_fns", at least in my TOT compiled version.

Comment: I like your approach of disassembling a C equivalent, I should have thought of doing that :-)

Answer (score 1):

this work well for me, xcode7.1 LLVM7.0 IOS9.1

In 32bit arm
 ldr r9,=JumpTab

Change to 64bit arm

adrp x9,JumpTab@PAGE
 add x9,x9,JumpTab@PAGEOFF

By the way,you need care registers' number, some registers have specific useful in arm64